# Is it possible to map values onto a table given corresponding row and column indices in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL table in the form of:

```
| value | row_loc | column_loc | 
|-------|---------|------------| 
| a     | 0       | 1          | 
| b     | 1       | 1          | 
| c     | 1       | 0          | 
| d     | 0       | 0          |
```

I would like to find a way to map it onto a table/grid, given the indices, using SQL. Something like:

```
| d     | a    | 
| c     | b    |
```

(The context being, I would like to create a colour map with colours corresponding to values a, b, c, d, in the locations specified)

I would be able to do this iteratively in python, but cannot figure out how to do it in SQL, or if it is even possible! Any help or guidance on this problem would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: a, b, c, d are examples of numeric values (which would not be able to be selected using named variables in practice, so I'm relying on selecting them based on location. Also worth noting, the number of rows and columns will always be the same. The value column is also not the primary key to this table, so is not necessarily unique, it is just as a continuous value.

Comment: To clarify, do you need `d` and `a` to be different _columns_, or is a concatenated row with `d,a` allowed? You could probably do something via `GROUP BY` to determine the row. So `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(value) FROM table GROUP BY row_loc` to get d/a on one row, and c/b on another row. Not sure yet about splitting d/a into separate columns based on the `column_loc`. Also, please add which DB engine you're using as a tag to your question.

Comment: Hi @WOUNDEDStevenJones thanks for your reply! I like that idea, but ideally I would like them as separate columns, so each value (a, b, c, d) would have their own separate 'cell' on a grid. I am not all that certain it's possible to do that though.

Comment: I don't like @WOUNDEDStevenJones's idea. It violates the simplest requirement of sound data modeling, known as First Normal Form. The correct solution is the one you already have - pivot the data into separate columns, not into a single string encoding distinct bits of data into a single value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, assuming the column number is limited since SQL supports only determined number of columns. The number of rows in result set depends on number of distinct `row_loc` values so we have to `group by` column `row_loc`. Then choose value using simple `case`.

```sql
with t (value, row_loc, column_loc) as (
  select 'a', 0, 1 from dual union all 
  select 'b', 1, 1 from dual union all 
  select 'c', 1, 0 from dual union all 
  select 'd', 0, 0 from dual
)
select max(case column_loc when 0 then value else null end) as column0
     , max(case column_loc when 1 then value else null end) as column1
from t
group by row_loc
order by row_loc
```

I tested it on Oracle. Not sure what to do if multiple values match on same coordinate, I chose max. For different vendors you could also utilize special clauses such as `count ... filter (where ...)`. Or the Oracle `pivot` clause can also be used.

Comment: Hi Tomáš, thanks for your response. I'm using Oracle too, and just tested it and works perfectly for this particular example. However, apologies I didn't mention in my question, a, b, c, d are numeric values, which would not be able to be selected with a variable name like 'a'. Do you think this approach still work in this case?
 (I've tried replacing 'a' in your example with a 'select value from table where row_loc=0 and column_loc=1' - not currently working but I'm wondering if this is an approach that would be appropriate for this?)

Comment: @ainwotal - the **with** clause is there only for testing purposes. In real life, remove it, and use your real-life table and column names. The query should work unchanged if the values are numeric (or any other data type for that matter). Really the only constraint is that the number of values in the `column_loc` column, as well as all the specific values in that column, have to be known in advance.

Comment: @ainwotal I have nothing to add to mathguy's comment, it's precisely said.